# вывод неографа в Graphviz c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/iteration_macros.hpp>
#define _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    ifstream in("input.txt");
    ofstream out("output.txt");
    out << "graph { " << endl;
    int m;//кол-во ребер
    int n;//кол-во вершин
    in >> n;
    in >> m;
    int x, y, z;//считываем дуги и вес
    vector < pair < int, pair<int, int> > > g(m); // вес - вершина 1 - вершина 2 

    vector < pair<int, int> > res;//массив для хранения дуг остовного дерева


    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        in >> x >> y >> z;
        g[i].first = z;
        g[i].second.first = x;
        g[i].second.second = y;
    }
    int tree_weight = 0;
    int cost = 0;
    sort(g.begin(), g.end());

    vector<int> tree_id(n);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n+1; i++) {
        tree_id.push_back(NULL);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n+1; ++i)
        tree_id[i] = i;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        int a = g[i].second.first, b = g[i].second.second, l = g[i].first;
        if (tree_id[a] != tree_id[b])
        {
            cost += l;
            res.push_back(make_pair(a, b));
            int old_id = tree_id[b], new_id = tree_id[a];
            for (int j = 0; j < n+1; ++j)
                if (tree_id[j] == old_id)
                    tree_id[j] = new_id;
        }
    }
    cout << "Ребра минимального остовного дерева: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < res.size(); i++) {
        out << res[i].first << "--" << res[i].second<<";"<<endl;
        cout << res[i].first << " , " << res[i].second << endl;
    }
    out << "}";
    cout << "Вес минимального остовного дерева: "<<cost<<endl;
    system("dot output.txt -Tpng -og.png");
}
```

Сделал алгоритм крускала. Вывел граф в текстовый файл в таком виде:

graph {

2--4;

3--4;

1--2;

3--5;

4--6;

}

Пишет syntax error in line 7. То есть это там, где скобка. А что не так здесь?Я в файл все это пустых строчек писал(просто тут нельзя так вписать).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я попробовал это граф пропустить через dot - все компилирует и работает.

Comment: У меня тоже сработало. Попробуйте добавить пробелы вокруг `--` и убрать `;`.

Comment: да я прям скопипастил

Comment: не помогло.он почему-то на скобку ругается. Я не знаю.Я вот в другом проекте просто вставил какой-то орграф,он картинку вывел.В этом проекте я пытаюсь сделать неограф и от он ругается на строчку со скобкой. Бред какой-то. С кодировкой что-то не то?

Comment: вот еще скрин добавил

Comment: Я написал то же самое вручную в другой файл и оно работает. Тут реально че-то с кодировкой. Может поток вывода в файл символы не той кодировки выводит?